# Do corpses of unique enemies/NPC disappear?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I wanted to collect all paragon gems.

However, I already killed one of the ice giant and I couldn't find that guy anymore. No problem. I just watch youtube video and go to the location of the giants. Sure enough, the corpse is still there.

Now, I want to do the quest that requires 8 dragon priest masks. It turns out, I do not have krosis.

So I go to shearpoint https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Krosis

Voila, no Krosis. I must have killed him a long time ago and I have no idea where I put the mask.

Now, I wonder why Krosis body isn't there?

So I just did things like

```
player.moveto 000F8A48
```

out of curiosity

No reference id. Krosis is really gone. Of course, I can just add Krosis Mask using console, but I want this to be more lore friendly.

Note:

```
player.moveto 000F8A48
```

actually move my character somewhere if I am near shearpoint but not when I am far away. I must be missing something. I don't see his corpse though.

Comment: As a point of refinement, it he's a dragon priest he wouldn't be a corpse, but an ash pile. But presumably you mean the same thing? I killed Vokun months ago in High Gate Ruins and his ash pile is still there.

Comment: Also - https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35321/do-corpses-disappear-after-a-while?rq=1

Comment: Ah. I moved to that place and didn't found ashpile either. I finally move Krosis to my location and resurrect him. He's there complete with mask and staff. I wonder if I had killed him before? Perhaps, resurrect restore items?

Comment: @c26 yea, another answer says that the bodies will disappear. That's strange. That's because I managed to find bodies of frost giants I killed long after I leave the places and do so many other quests.

Comment: In Morrowind, there is some kind of "garbage room" only accessible via console commands where dead unique characters are put into. I'm pretty sure skyrim does the same.